# Does JMockit initialize EJBs?

Tags: java, tdd, jmockit

I'm trying to understand JMockit but still I'm running into walls.

This is a class I want to test:

```
@Stateless
public class VerfahrensArchivService {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;


public void storeAndUpdateVerfahren(List<Verfahren> pVerfahrenToStore) {

    if (pVerfahrenToStore == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("pVerfahrenToStore darf nicht null sein!");
    }

    for (Verfahren verfahren : pVerfahrenToStore) {

        Verfahren storedCopy = getVerfahrenByExterneID(verfahren.getFremdsystem(), verfahren.getExterneId());

        if (storedCopy == null){
            //Ein neues Verfahren wurde gefunden!

            em.persist(verfahren);
        }else{

        }

    }

}
}
```

This is how my test looks like:

```
public class VerfahrensArchivServiceTest {

@Tested
private VerfahrensArchivService archiveService;

@NonStrict //Also tried simple @Mocked
private EntityManager em;


@Test
public void should_store_new_verfahren_to_persistence_layer(){


    List<Verfahren> listeMitEinemNeuenVerfahren = new ArrayList<Verfahren>();
    Verfahren v = new Verfahren();
    v.setId(0);
    v.setExterneId("Neu");
    v.setFremdsystem(Verfahren.FREMDSYSTEM_P);
    listeMitEinemNeuenVerfahren.add(v);


    new NonStrictExpectations(archiveService) { 
        {
            //simulate that nothing was found in the db  
            archiveService.getVerfahrenByExterneID(anyString, anyString);result = null;
        }
    };

    new Expectations() {
        {
            em.persist(any);
        }
    };

    archiveService.storeAndUpdateVerfahren(listeMitEinemNeuenVerfahren);

}



}
```

The test fails because EntityManager is null in the moment of calling em.persist().
Why?
Is the test structured the right way? If not, could you show me how I do better?

I really believe that JMockit will help me be more productive in a TDD way. But I need to understand how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the @Tested Javadoc little bit more carefully. There it states, that you could use test method parameters to setup the @Tested/class under test. Just declare a @Incectable parameter of the type you need. Read the @Tested javadoc to find out how the params are matched to the uninitialized fields.

so, my test works with this:

```
@Test
public void should_store_new_verfahren_to_persistence_layer(@Injectable final EntityManager em){


    List<Verfahren> listeMitEinemNeuenVerfahren = new ArrayList<Verfahren>();
    Verfahren v = new Verfahren();
    v.setId(0);
    v.setExterneId("Neu");
    v.setFremdsystem(Verfahren.FREMDSYSTEM_P);
    listeMitEinemNeuenVerfahren.add(v);


    new NonStrictExpectations(archiveService) { 
        {
            archiveService.getVerfahrenByExterneID(anyString, anyString);result = null;
        }
    };

    new Expectations() {
        {
            em.persist(any);
        }
    };

    archiveService.storeAndUpdateVerfahren(listeMitEinemNeuenVerfahren);

}
```

Comment: Btw: 1 year later I switched to Mockito. It is so much easier to use. And it does not allow for bad code. JMockit tollerates to much. ;)